# Eventual RabbitMQ crash

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, spring-rabbit, erl, epmd

I would like to understand the logs of a RabbitMQ error. Can anyone help me decipher the following error message:

[image]

The interesting thing is that in my case, I have a server running with RabbitMQ 3.8.8 running and erlang 23 behind it, but suddenly after a long period running this crash occurred.

Maybe it's related to port 25672 connectivity?

The error repeated for a few hours until we noticed and then the whole server was restarted, this fact made the rabbitmq run again and everything went well.

So the question is, what does this error mean, that port 25672 doesn't respond?

Comment: I suggest you to post your problem on the RabbitMQ Mailing List: https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users. Doesn't look like this has to do anything with Spring.

Comment: The [open_port](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#open_port-2) doc states that `eaccess` is usually triggered when the file is not executable.
There's even a message telling to install [handle.exe from sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle)
However, the `eaccess` for `erl.exe` is really strange. (And even more if this happened after the server was up for a long time)